# Haskell, stuck on understanding type synonyms

Tags: haskell

From LYAH book, parameterizing type synonyms:
I would understand:

```
type MyName = String
```

But this example I don't get:

```
type IntMap v = Map Int v -- let alone it can be shortened
```

'Map' is a function, not a type, right? This got me in loops in the book constantly now. Next to that: Map would require a function and a list to work, correct? If so, and 'v' is the list, what is the 'Int'?

Comment: _This is a `map`, and this is a `Map`. This is a function, and this is a type._

Comment: Things that start with a capital letter are not functions.

Answer (score 8):

[`Map`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#t%3AMap) is the name of a type. It's an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and maps values of type `T` to values of type `K`. So `IntMap` is the type of a `Map` which has `Int` keys and `v` values. Maps are also known as dictionaries in some languages. They're implemented by hash tables, balanced trees or other more exotic data structures.

It's an unfortunate name collision that there's also the `map` function. They *kind of* do the same thing, only in different contexts. `map` transforms values in the input by applying a function to them, whereas `Map` transforms input keys to output values.

Comment: Addendum: `Map` is Haskell's name for what some other languages call a _dictionary_.

Answer (score 1):

There is a type named `Map` (with a capital "M"). There is also a function named `map` (with a lowercase "M"). These are unrelated other than having kind-of similar names. Try not to confuse them. ;-)